# how to pass a string variable as part of xml's name

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I d like some guidance on how how to pass a string variable as part of an xml name.
I m running a mysql query according to the users form selection.Then i create an xml for the result.I d like to pass a  variable as the name of the xml.How is this possible?

thats my working code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE diam = '$d' AND nom = '$n' AND dim = '$di' AND type = '$t'";
$query_result=mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_result);
if($num_rows == 0) {

    echo "bummer!";

} else {

    #Creates a new DOMDocument
    $doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");

    #formats correctly the xml document 
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    #Create Parent Node
    $parent_node = $doc->createElement('marker');
    $parent_node = $doc->appendChild($parent_node);

    #Row manip
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
        #adds node for each row
        $row_node = $doc->createElement($table);
        #appends the new node to the root
        $occ = $parent_node->appendChild($row_node);

        #add a child node for each field
        foreach($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
            $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
            $child = $occ->appendChild($child);

            $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
            $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }
    }

    #saves generated domDocument into a file.
    #If echo'ed outputs filezise in bytes
    $xml_string = $doc->save('xmlOutput.xml');
}
```

instead of the hardcoded "xmlOutput" i d like to display ,lets say the diam column name.

Comment: Emm... You can use `$d` variable... Or I don't understand something?

`$xml_string = $doc->save($d);`

Comment: `$name_of_file = 'somefile.xml'; $doc->save($name_of_file)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop where you loop through the result:

```
#Row manip
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
```

you can access the value of the `diam` column by doing:

```
$diam = $row['diam'];
```

---

I noticed now that you might be asking for:

```
$filename = $d . '.xml';
$xml_string = $doc->save($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you dynamically create the output file name? Something like this..

```
$ouputFile = $row['diam'] . '.xml';
$xml_string = $doc->save($outputFile);
```

Comment: I couldnt add the ".xml" extension in one line,right after passing the string into the files name.The above line did the work.Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh damn,i probably missclicked it yesterday night.I m still not used on how this site works.Needs 15 rep to vote up.I ll fix this as soon  as i get 2 more rep.Apologies again and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically create a filename then you can use the `$d` variable (which corresponds with your diam column).

```
$fileName = $d . '.xml';
$xml_string = $doc->save($fileName);
```